# Differential loading not working in Angular 12: "Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token ':'"

Tags: node.js, angular, typescript, webpack, angular12

I recently came across the error of bundle size exceeding the budget limits in our Angular 12 project. While implementing several ways to reduce the bundle size, differential loading was one such way. Angular provides this as default and enables this for you once you set your `target` to `es2015` in your `tsconfig.app.json` and your `.browserslistrc` configuration.

But to my surprise, something is not working even after following the above two steps. We are using `@angular-builders/custom-webpack` as our builder. In our custom webpack configuration we are just using `DefinePlugin` to add some environment specific variables.

My **angular.json**:

```js
"architect": {
    "build": {
        "builder": "@angular-builders/custom-webpack:browser",
        "options": {
            "outputPath": "dist/apps/my-project",
            "index": "apps/my-project/src/index.html",
            "main": "apps/my-project/src/main.ts",
            "polyfills": "apps/my-project/src/polyfills.ts",
            "tsConfig": "apps/my-project/tsconfig.app.json",
            "aot": true,
            "customWebpackConfig": {
                "path": "apps/my-project/webpack.config.js",
                "mergeRules": {
                    "externals": "replace"
                }
            }
        },
        "configurations": {
            "prod": {
                "outputPath": "dist/apps/my-project-prod",
                "customWebpackConfig": {
                    "path": "apps/my-project/webpack.prod.partial.js",
                    "mergeRules": {
                        "externals": "replace"
                    }
                },
                "baseHref": "https://my-project.com/",
                "fileReplacements": [
                    {
                        "replace": "apps/my-project/src/environments/environment.ts",
                        "with": "apps/my-project/src/environments/environment.prod.ts"
                    }
                ],
                "index": {
                    "input": "apps/my-project/src/index.prod.html",
                    "output": "/index.html"
                },
                "optimization": true,
                "outputHashing": "all",
                "sourceMap": false,
                "namedChunks": false,
                "aot": true,
                "extractLicenses": true,
                "vendorChunk": false,
                "buildOptimizer": true,
                "budgets": [
                    {
                        "type": "initial",
                        "maximumWarning": "2mb",
                        "maximumError": "5mb"
                    }
                ]
            }
        }
    },
    "serve": {
        "builder": "@angular-builders/custom-webpack:dev-server",
        "options": {
            "host": "localhost",
            "baseHref": "http://localhost:3000",
            "port": 3000,
            "browserTarget": "my-project:build"
        },
        "configurations": {
            "prod": {
                "browserTarget": "my-project:build:prod"
            }
        }
    }
}
```

My **tsconfig.app.json**:

```js
{
    "extends": "./tsconfig.json",
    "compilerOptions": {
       "outDir": "../../dist/out-tsc/apps/my-project",
        "types": ["node"],
        "typeRoots": [
            "./src/customTypes"
        ]
    },
    "exclude": [
        "src/test.ts",
        "**/*.spec.ts"
    ],
    "files": [
        "src/main.ts",
        "src/polyfills.ts",
    ],
    "include": [
        "src/**/*.ts"
    ]
}
```

Parent **tsconfig.json**:

```js
{
    "compileOnSave": false,
    "compilerOptions": {
        "inlineSources": true,
        "sourceMap": true,
        "declaration": false,
        "moduleResolution": "node",
        "emitDecoratorMetadata": true,
        "experimentalDecorators": true,
        "importHelpers": true,
        "target": "es2015",
        "module": "es2020",
        "typeRoots": [
            "node_modules/@types"
        ],
        "lib": [
            "es2018",
            "dom"
        ],
        "skipLibCheck": true,
        "skipDefaultLibCheck": true,
        "baseUrl": "./"
    },
    "exclude": [
        "node_modules",
        "tmp"
    ]
}
```

My **.browserslistrc**:

```
last 1 Chrome version
last 1 Firefox version
last 2 Edge major versions
last 2 Safari major versions
last 2 iOS major versions
Firefox ESR
not IE 11
```

As per the [docs](https://angular.io/guide/deployment#differential-builds), you can verify if differential loading is working by looking at your `index.html` file's `<script>` tag:

```html
<body>
  <app-root></app-root>
  <script src="runtime-es2015.js" type="module"></script>
  <script src="runtime-es5.js" nomodule></script>
  <script src="polyfills-es2015.js" type="module"></script>
  <script src="polyfills-es5.js" nomodule></script>
  <script src="styles-es2015.js" type="module"></script>
  <script src="styles-es5.js" nomodule></script>
  <script src="vendor-es2015.js" type="module"></script>
  <script src="vendor-es5.js" nomodule></script>
  <script src="main-es2015.js" type="module"></script>
  <script src="main-es5.js" nomodule></script>
</body>
```

My `index.html`'s `<script>` tags looks like this:

```html
<script src="runtime.f03314b4ecbf857f30db.js" defer></script>
<script src="polyfills.b4a4dc722533999c6a79.js" defer></script>
<script src="scripts.d0fcd864b87b7eb9e1e6.js" defer></script>
<script src="vendor.2070a0076d5aa66a3b91.js" defer></script>
<script src="main.c7fdac1323ac33ecb488.js" defer></script>
```

I can't seem to find either `es5` or `es2015` keywords in it. Neither I could find `type=module` or `nomodule`. My bundle size surely got reduced but my project is not working either on the serve or after deployment. I am getting the below error in the console of the browser (`Chrome 91.0.4472.101`) which is unclear:

[image]

My **polyfill.ts**:

```ts
import 'core-js/es/reflect';
import '@angular/localize/init';
import 'zone.js/dist/zone';
(window as any)['global'] = window;
```

I came across this [issue](https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/issues/14911) which states that differential loading doesn't take place during serve but for me it is also not working after deployment. Just to avoid any configurational errors I also created a fresh demo project in Angular 12 and everything is working fine there. I have also matched the values of the above files. The only differences that I found were:

- Custom webpack is not used in the demo project
- `polyfill.ts` only contained import of Zone.js

**Even the demo project's `index.html` didn't contain the `es5`, `es2015`, `module`, `nomodule` keywords and was similar to my project's `index.html`**.

I have spent a lot of time on this but can't find any solution. Please let me know if I am missing anything.

Comment: I don't understand why do any of this. Ng9 I believe started to offer lazy loading of modules out of the box. You simply load the module you need when you want to use it and this decreases the size significantly. It automatically creates these small files for each module you load because of the AOT. No need for differential loading or custom web pack

Comment: @misha130 We are already using the rest of the best practices (and lazy loading came well before Ng9 :)), but the problem I am highlighting here is of differential loading as I am unable to carry out an important Angular feature.

Comment: I am not talking lazy loading via routing though

Comment: @misha130 we are already using that but any idea why the differential loading isn't working?